# Select Records multiple times from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL statement like this:

**EDIT :**

```
SELECT 
    location as Location 
FROM
    Table1 
WHERE 
    OnsiteOffshore = 'Offshore' AND Acc_Code = 'ABC' 

UNION 

SELECT 
    Country 
FROM 
    Table1 
WHERE
    OnsiteOffshore = 'Onsite' AND Acc_Code = 'ABC'
```

This SQL query gives these results:

```
Chennai
Bangalore
USA
NewZealand
```

But due to some requirement I need the output like this:

```
Chennai
Chennai
Chennai
Chennai
Bangalore
Bangalore
Bangalore
Bangalore
USA
USA
USA
USA
NewZealand
NewZealand
NewZealand
NewZealand
```

Mean to say each location needs to be output 4 times.

Pls help how to get the same.

Comment: if there were 5 locations would you expect to see each location listed 5 times and if 3 only 3 times etc?

Comment: @sukumar: There are numerous questions you have asked. Some have pretty good answers. Why don't you accept the answers that have helped you?

Comment: @ypercube: I updated my SQL statment. Now how can i get the result multiple of 4 times. 

Surely i'll accept the answer

Comment: I was not talking about this question/asnwers but previous questions of yours.

Comment: @sukumar: did we ever find out if your results only returned 3 locations if you would only expect each location listed 3 times? in in the case of 5 different locations being returned each one should be listed 5 times?

Comment: @ypercube, Thanks for your comment surely i'll accept the answers for earlier question within end of this year 2011.

Comment: ... Yes we found out or yes we want to have 3x3 5x5 (if yes 3x3 5x5 then see @hyper's 2nd option or any of mine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT Location 
FROM Table1
  CROSS JOIN
    ( VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
    ) AS four(dummy)
```

If the `4` is not a constant but (as @xQbert noticed/asked) is the number of rows of the table, you can use this:

```
SELECT a.Location 
FROM Table1 AS a
  CROSS JOIN
     Table1 AS b
```

---

If you don't have `Table1` but any (however complex) query, you could use this for 4 copies:

```
SELECT Location 
FROM (
       SELECT Location       --- complex query here
       ...                   --- inside parenthesis
     UNION 
       SELECT Country
       ...
     ) AS Table1
  CROSS JOIN
    ( VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
    ) AS four(dummy)
```

or this for `n` copies:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT Location       --- complex query here
    ...                   --- inside parenthesis
    UNION 
    SELECT Country
    ...
  )
SELECT a.Location 
FROM cte AS a
  CROSS JOIN
     cte AS b
```

Comment: @amit: (the `VALUES (...)` syntax is) available only in SQL-Server 2008+

Comment: @sukumar: Just replace `FROM Table1` with `FROM (SELECT ...) AS Table1`

Comment: @ypercube, I couldn't get with your comment. Please can you help with query.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest and (probably) fully accepted in any RDBMS ;-):

```
select location from (
    Select Location From Table1 union all
    Select Location From Table1 union all
    Select Location From Table1 union all
    Select Location From Table1
) t
order by location
```

And better way with [CTE (Common Table Expressions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
;with cte (id) as (
    select 1 union all
    select id + 1 from cte where id < 4
)
select location from Table1
cross join cte
```

Comment: +1 for the CTE, although I'm tempted to -1 for the first query. :)

Comment: @MarkBannister, I know that was bit silly but simplest and (probably) fully accepted in any RDBMS ;-). Removed.

Comment: I didn't mean you should remove it - as you said, it should (probably) be fully accepted in any RDBMS...

Comment: I put you +1 for the first query (and because it should work in previous versions of SQL-Server and in most DBMS). Now, I'm tempted to remove my upvote :)

Comment: @ypercube, I've rolled back with info :-).

Comment: Hi, Just want to know what is CTE here in the above context.

Comment: @sukumar, CTE stands for [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) quite nice thing added in SQL Server 2005 especially for recursive queries.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper procedure for this... where u first create a cursor for `Select Location From Table1` than you can loop through this cursor and extract the data whatever way want.

optionally you can use some front end technology to do this. This is not a tough task in front end languages i.e. Java, C++, .NET or in any other popular language.

Comment: Why would you use a cursor if you can do it *any other way*?

Answer (score 2):

Will only work if Table1 has at least 4 records

```
SELECT Location
FROM Table1 a, (select top 4 id from Table1) b 
order by a.Location
```

Comment: and if it has an `id` column.

Comment: You could use * instead. I wonder if there is a difference in efficiency?

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @counter int
DECLARE @max int = 4

CREATE TABLE #myTable (
    Name nvarchar(50)
)

SET @counter = 0

WHILE @counter < @max

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #myTable SELECT cityname FROM citytable

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END


SELECT name FROM #myTable ORDER BY name

DROP TABLE #myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.location 
from table1 t1, table1 t2
```

should return n locations of n.  so if locations contain 10 entries, one of which is USA, USA would be listed 10 times.  This scales depending on the number of locations entered.

or a more modern syntax:

```
Select t1.location
from table1 t1
Cross join table1 t2
```

notice the lack of an ON clause; that's because we want the Cartesian product of the self join.

--EDIT reflecting changed SQL

```
Select A.Location 
FROM (
  Select  location as Location 
  from Table1 where OnsiteOffshore = 'Offshore' and Acc_Code = 'ABC' 
  UNION 
  Select  Country 
  from Table1 where OnsiteOffshore = 'Onsite' and Acc_Code = 'ABC') A
CROSS JOIN (
  Select  location as Location 
  from Table1 where OnsiteOffshore = 'Offshore' and Acc_Code = 'ABC' 
  UNION 
  Select  Country 
  from Table1 where OnsiteOffshore = 'Onsite' and Acc_Code = 'ABC') B
```

Comment: just missed the `A.` in `Select A.Location `

Comment: @xQbert: Your query results 10times of each string. but i need only 4 times. please help

Comment: The only way I would have 10 times is if there are 10 distinct location & Country. if you ONLY need 4, then ypercube's or michal's responses are more correct.

Answer (score 0):

8-)

```
Select Location From Table1 UNION ALL
Select Location From Table1 UNION ALL
Select Location From Table1 UNION ALL
Select Location From Table1 
ORDER BY 1
```