# How do I get multiple rows when value > 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select Records multiple times from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679067/select-records-multiple-times-from-table)

I want to have my query return (multiple) rows for the value of TABLE_B.QTY.

```
TABLE A
SALESNR  ITEMNR LINENR
100      B2001  1
101      B2002  2
102      A1021  3 

TABLE B 
LINENR   COLOR QTY
1        WHITE  3  
2        BLACK  1
3        BROWN  8
```

For instance, with the following query:

```
SELECT    TABLE_A.SALESNR, TABLE_A.ITEMNR, TABLE_B.COLOR, TABLE_B.QTY
FROM       TABLE_A  INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.LINENR = TABLE_A.LINENR
```

I get:

```
100    B2001   White   3
```

What I need is:

```
100    B2001   White   3
100    B2001   White   3
100    B2001   White   3
```

Is there a way to do this?
Can't think of the right keywords to Google this...

Thnx,

Mike

Comment: hi ypercube, yep I've simplified the tables as an example but because of the join on linenr 1 <-> 1 I get only one row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work as long as QTY is less than 2047

```
SELECT TABLE_A.SALESNR, TABLE_A.ITEMNR, TABLE_B.COLOR, TABLE_B.QTY 
FROM TABLE_A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.LINENR = TABLE_A.LINENR 
INNER JOIN master..spt_values ON type = 'P' AND number < TABLE_B.QTY
```

use this if QTY exceeds 2047:

```
;WITH a AS
(
SELECT TABLE_A.SALESNR, TABLE_A.ITEMNR, TABLE_B.COLOR, TABLE_B.QTY, 1 row
FROM TABLE_A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.LINENR = TABLE_A.LINENR 
WHERE QTY > 0
union all
SELECT SALESNR, ITEMNR, COLOR, QTY, row+1 
FROM a
WHERE QTY > row 
)
SELECT SALESNR, ITEMNR, COLOR, QTY from a
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Butter my butt and call me a biscuit ;)
You're the man t-clausen, thanks a million!!

Comment: @MikeDole I was just the lucky guy who found the question first

Answer (score 0):

The cross join won't do it if you have one row in each table, which I interpret it as. I would suggest, if possible, to re-design your data model to solve this - or loop in code where you use this data.

You can loop in the T-SQL if absolutely needed.

regards, Olle

Can't seem to comment other peoples posts, just wanted to say, nice solution, to t-clausen.dk!