# SQL: How to select some (but not all) records in a query multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a bunch of records and we assign a random number to each record whose value is between 1 and the total number of records in the following manner:

```
SELECT personID, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNumber
FROM folks
```

Easy like pie. Let's assume that a LOWER (edit: NOT higher, sorry!) number is better for Customer's purposes, and that they like how the 'random' element here works. Trouble is, customer now says 'some people are special and we want them to get three chances, and then save their best result as their number.'

Since we don't hand out numbers serially but all at once, the approach here seems to be to select special people three times in this query, and then grab their highest row number.

This is similar to, but one step more involved than this question (and others like it):

[Select Records multiple times from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679067/select-records-multiple-times-from-table)

I don't want to select ALL records three times; but I do want to do everything in one go; that is, I can't assign special people numbers, and then assign everyone else numbers - it has to be one query.

1. How would I construct a JOIN (and/or a CTE) to model this, assuming we can rely on a field like `isSpecial = 1` on each record?
2. How would I then grab the 'lowest number' (i.e. first `row_number` appearance of that record) from the result in my `SELECT` statement?

Platform: Microsoft SQL 2012

SAMPLE DATA (including isSpecial in the output query just for demonstration's sake) - also, we want the minimum number here for business purposes, not the maximum

```
personID    isSpecial
1           1
2           0
3           0
4           0
5           0
6           0
7           0
8           0
9           0
10          0
```

Current output:

```
SELECT personID, isSpecial, row_number
OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNumber
FROM folks

personID    RowNumber    isSpecial
8           1            0
2           2            0
10          3            0
1           4            1
9           5            0
3           6            0
4           7            0
6           8            0
5           9            0
7           10            0
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
personID    MinRowNumber isSpecial rowNumber1 rowNumber2 rowNumber3
8           1            0         1
2           2            0         2
1           3            1         4          7          3
9           5            0         5
3           6            0         6
6           8            0         8
5           9            0         9
7           10           0         10
4           11           0         11         
10          12           0         12
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't need to select them three times but change your row_number to be a calculation based on the weight of isSpecial

Comment: Not sure how many times you are running this, but if its not too many, you might want to just go the easy way and create a UDF that does this for you and returns the highest. You could also include a parameter for how many changes, so if they decide they want to change it later on it easy to do without redeployment

Comment: need some sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using a tally table and some aggregation. Something along these lines.

```
WITH
cteTally(N) AS (select n from (values (1),(2),(3))dt(n))

select personID
    , MAX(RowNumber)
from 
(
    SELECT personID
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNumber
    FROM folks f
    join cteTally t on t.N <= case when f.IsSpecial = 1 then 3 else 1 end
) x
group by x.personID
```

--EDIT--

You stated you might want all rows not just the MAX one. Here is how you could do that.

```
WITH
cteTally(N) AS (select n from (values (1),(2),(3))dt(n))

SELECT personID
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNumber
FROM folks f
join cteTally t on t.N <= case when f.IsSpecial = 1 then 3 else 1 end
```

Comment: This looks like it does the trick! What if I also wanted the other 2 values for posterity - that is, in addition to the MAX, what if I just wanted all the row_numbers in my SELECT?

Comment: If you want all of them then just use the inner query and completely drop the outer one. You would still need the cte though to generate all three rows for those that need it.

Comment: It may not matter to you for your purposes, but the first query will leave gaps in the numbering. EDIT: I see that your sample output also has gaps.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If we have 10 people, there will only be ten final 'ranks' even if we've generated 12 ranks due to the presence of one Special person. While we want to record all ranks for posterity, we're only going to use 1 rank per person, so gaps are OK.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this, but wanted to ask a quick question about the syntax. This solution worked for us (thank you!). What is dt() in TSQL?

Comment: dt is the name I gave to the table derived using a table valued constructor. Then (n) is the list of column names (there is only column here so only 1 name). You can read more about them here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the UNION approach, but only apply NEWID() once:

```
create table folks (personID int, isSpecial int)

insert into folks values (1,1);
insert into folks values (2,0);
insert into folks values (3,0);
insert into folks values (4,0);
insert into folks values (5,0);
insert into folks values (6,0);
insert into folks values (7,0);
insert into folks values (8,0);
insert into folks values (9,0);
insert into folks values (10,0);

select * from folks;

select
   personID,
   min(rownumber) as min_rownumber
from
  (SELECT 
      personID, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNumber
   FROM 
      (select personID from folks 
      union all
      select personID from folks where isSpecial = 1 
      union all
      select personID from folks where isSpecial = 1) u
   ) r
group by
   personID
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd4b79)

Comment: but you want the MIN(rownumber) instead of the MAX?  Also assuming you don't need the rownumber detail for the special people pivoted, just the MIN result

Comment: This does do what I originally asked for - I'll end up using Sean's answer just because it turned out we do need the 'interim' numbers (not just the min or max) but I like the alternate approach.

Comment: if you want all the numbers, remove the `min()` function and the `group by` clause, same as the other answers

Answer (score 1):

A correct way to solve the task is this.

Let we have `O` ordinary people plus `S` special people. Each ordinary person has one chance, each special person has 3 chances. We should generate `O` plus `S * 3` random numbers evenly distributed in the range of `[1 .. O+S*3]`, then order all people according to the numbers that they got. Special people will appear 3 times in this ordered list, ordinary people will appear only once.

Here is the query that does it. The code for creating the table with sample data is shown below in my first variant. `CTE_Numbers` is just a table with three numbers. If you want to give a different number of chances to special people, alter this query. `CTE` lists all ordinary people once plus all special people three times. `CTE_rn` assigns a random number to each row. Each special person gets three random numbers. As each special person has three rows in `CTE_rn`, final query groups by `PersonID` and leaves only one row for each special person with the minimum number. To get a better understanding how it works, examine the intermediate results of `CTE_rn`.

```
WITH
CTE_Numbers
AS
(
    SELECT Number
    FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) AS N(Number)
)
,CTE
AS
(
    -- list ordinary people only once
    SELECT PersonID,IsSpecial
    FROM @T
    WHERE IsSpecial = 0

    UNION ALL

    -- list each special person three times
    SELECT PersonID,IsSpecial
    FROM @T CROSS JOIN CTE_Numbers
    WHERE IsSpecial = 1
)
,CTE_rn
AS
(
    SELECT
        PersonID,IsSpecial
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) AS rn
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    PersonID,IsSpecial
    ,MIN(rn) AS FinalRank
FROM CTE_rn
GROUP BY PersonID,IsSpecial
ORDER BY FinalRank;
```

**result**

```
PersonID    IsSpecial    FinalRank
9           0            1
2           0            2
1           1            3
10          0            4
8           0            5
5           0            6
3           0            7
7           0            9
4           0            10
6           0            12
```

Note, how `FinalRank` has values from 1 to 12 (not 10) and values 8 and 11 are not shown. The special person had them. Special person got random numbers 3, 8, 11 and the final result contains only minimum out of these three.

---

The first variant. It works, but results are skewed.

Very straight-forward. Generate random row numbers three times, join them together and for ordinary people pick the result of the first random number, for special people pick the minimum of three runs.

Nobody promised any particular distribution of random numbers for `NEWID`, so you'd better not use it in this case. In this example I used `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`.

I put the same query to get random numbers in three separate CTEs, rather than using the same CTE in the join, to make sure that it is calculated three times. If you use a single CTE, the server may be smart enough to calculate random numbers only once, rather than three times and this not what we need here. We do need 30 calls to `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` here.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (PersonID int, IsSpecial bit);

INSERT INTO @T(PersonID, IsSpecial) VALUES
(1 , 1),
(2 , 0),
(3 , 0),
(4 , 0),
(5 , 0),
(6 , 0),
(7 , 0),
(8 , 0),
(9 , 0),
(10, 0);

WITH
CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT PersonID, IsSpecial,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) AS rn
    FROM @T
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT PersonID, IsSpecial,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) AS rn
    FROM @T
)
,CTE3
AS
(
    SELECT PersonID, IsSpecial,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) AS rn
    FROM @T
)
,CTE_All
AS
(
SELECT
    CTE1.PersonID
    ,CTE1.IsSpecial
    ,CTE1.rn AS rn1
    ,CTE2.rn AS rn2
    ,CTE3.rn AS rn3
    ,CA.MinRN
FROM
    CTE1
    INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE2.PersonID = CTE1.PersonID
    INNER JOIN CTE3 ON CTE3.PersonID = CTE1.PersonID
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT MIN(A.rn) AS MinRN
        FROM (VALUES (CTE1.rn), (CTE2.rn), (CTE3.rn)) AS A(rn)
    ) AS CA
)
SELECT
    PersonID
    ,IsSpecial
    ,CASE WHEN IsSpecial = 0 
    THEN rn1 -- a person is not special, he gets random rank from the first run only
    ELSE MinRN -- a special person, he gets a rank that is minimum of three runs
    END AS FinalRank
    ,rn1
    ,rn2
    ,rn3
    ,MinRN
FROM CTE_All
ORDER BY FinalRank;
```

**result set**

```
PersonID    IsSpecial    FinalRank    rn1    rn2    rn3    MinRN
8           0            1            1      1      1      1
6           0            2            2      7      2      2
5           0            3            3      5      6      3
1           1            3            9      3      4      3
4           0            4            4      6      3      3
7           0            5            5      9      10     5
3           0            6            6      8      9      6
2           0            7            7      2      8      2
10          0            8            8      10     5      5
9           0            10           10     4      7      4
```

You can see that special people can (by chance) get the same rank as ordinary people. You can favor special people further and make sure that they appear before ordinary people in this case. Just alter `ORDER BY` to be `ORDER BY FinalRank, IsSpecial DESC`.

Comment: Aren't the ties going to cause problems? Couldn't there be as many as three people with the same MinRN?

Comment: @shawnt00, There can be as many as Special people with the same MinRN. If there is 1 Special person, it can have the same Rank as one of the ordinary people. If there are 5 Special people, they all can have the same MinRN by chance and be the same as one of the ordinary person. To solve this kind of task properly, without these ties, the whole approach should be different.

Comment: @shawnt00, the correct solution is this. Let we have `O` ordinary people plus `S` special people. Each ordinary person has one chance, each special person has 3 chances. We should generate `O` plus `S * 3` random numbers evenly distributed in the range of `[1 .. O+S*3]`, then order all people according to the numbers that they got. Special people will appear 3 times in this ordered list, ordinary people will appear only once.

Comment: I agree with your second comment. But you can only have three with the same MinRN because you' re only joining the three tables.

Comment: @shawnt00, I added a second (correct) variant to the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately for our purposes, minRN must be unique.

Comment: @Aquitaine, My first attempt that uses `MinRN` has flaws, I added a second (correct) variant to the top of the answer. Now it is pretty much the same as answers by Sean Lange and Beth.

Answer (score 0):

How about using UNION?

```
SELECT personID, ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNumber
FROM folks
WHERE isSpecial = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT personID, MAX(RN)
FROM (    
    SELECT personID, ROW_NUMBER() AS 'RN'
        OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNumber
    FROM folks
    WHERE isSpecial = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT personID, ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNumber
    FROM folks
    WHERE isSpecial = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT personID, ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNumber
    FROM folks
    WHERE isSpecial = 1    
    )
GROUP BY personID
```

Comment: I guess this would produce conflicting row numbers.  Depends on what OP is looking for.